# Can't replace in Haskell

Tags: haskell, replace

I'm trying to read in a string from a file, which works fine. But trying to replace punctuation marks with nothing to delete them, it gives me always the same message.
My program part so far looks like this:

```
module HA

where

import FPH
import Data.List

let contents2 = replace "." "" sonnet18
let contents3 = replace "!" "" contents2
```

sonnet18 is a string in the file FPH.hs.
I tried a couple ways to replace it, but get always the exception "parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
It doesn't say much and looking it up, didn't help yet. All indentations are four whitespaces and so on. I can't find the mistake. I'm grateful for any help.

Comment: After adding the do-block it just gives me another error message:
"Variable not in scope: replace :: [Char] -> [Char] -> [Char] -> t"

Comment: What makes you expect `replace` to exist?

Comment: Since I'm doing it like it's done in a tutorial and they use it that way, I considered it to be part of the library I'm importing.

Comment: What tutorial? Show us.

Comment: Using qualified import can help to find where the things are from.

Comment: Please don't edit your code to fix the problem described in your post and leave all the original text describing the the problem that is now gone! Generally Stack Overflow would prefer you asked a separate question for each issue, but if you do decide to edit your question anyway then at least make sure the result of your edit is a complete question asking for help with the problem you actually have!

Comment: @DanielWagner I'm using this one: http://www.makechronicles.com/2012/11/11/first-steps-with-haskell-the-word-counter/

Comment: @Ben I exactly did this last time and everyone went crazy why I'd open another question for the same script and why I wouldn't have just edited my code. So that's the reason.

Comment: My main point your post now contains a substantially different program, and claims that your problem is a parse error. That's going to make it harder for people to help with your *actual* problem with *this* code, which has nothing to do with the parse error in your earlier code.

Comment: @Ben I thought that's what the versioning is there for but I changed it back and open up a new one.

Comment: I had a look at that tutorial, and it tells you to prepare by getting a library from here: https://github.com/jgoerzen/missingh. That's the library that contains `replace` (in `Data.List.Utils`), not `Data.List.Split`.

Comment: I'm still not being clear. I don't really mind if whether you edit the code in this post. I'm saying you should **also** edit the text of the post to describe your new problem!

Comment: I'm sorry if I misunderstood you. My English is, obviously not well enough. But since I have to install a library, I can't use this solution anyway. But thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use `let` at the toplevel like you do.
It is only needed while using the interpreter.

Comment: "[Top-level `let`] is only needed while using the interpreter." -- And not even in that case if you are using GHC 8.

Comment: Yes of course. I somehow thought I already tried to do it in a do block but obviously I didn't try... because it works. But now I get an issure with the missing expression.

Comment: Looks like it's not the only issue I have here.